# Find element similarity within a collection of strings without evaluating all element pairs

Tags: algorithm, heuristics, string-metric

So the problem collection is something like:

```
A = {'abc', 'abc', 'abd', 'bcde', 'acbdg', ...}
```

Using some type of [string metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) like Levenshtein distance, it's simple enough to find some sort of heuristic of string similarity between 2 strings.

However, I would like to determine, without evaluating all pairs of strings in the collection (an O(N^2) problem), some type of heuristic based on the entire collection that gives me a good idea of the overall similarity between all the strings.

The brute force approach is:

```
                          Sum(Metric(All Pairs in A))
CollectionSimilarity(A) = ---------------------------
                                 N*(N+1)/2
```

Is there a way to evaluate the similarity of the entire collection of A without evaluating every pair?

Comment: Is edit distance your definition of "similarity"? Like, what is your Platonic definition of similarity?

Comment: Something like 1/(Levenshtein distance), but the metric doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Defining the best heuristic would depend greatly on what you are trying to do in the end, but some possibilities would be the average of the distances between adjacent elements (`O(N)` instead of `O(N^2)`), or maybe the average of distances between one representative and all the other elements, or the average across a randomly-generated subset of all the pairs... There are plenty of others, but your actual problem domain would influence which of them is "best"...

Comment: Excellent point. For this problem, let's assume one representative is not a feasible solution (which would basically solve this problem). Adjacent elements is not feasible either in the case of A = {a,b,a,b,a,b,a,...}. Randomly-generated, or cleverly designed patterns like the one I just posited would be the ideal problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use some approximation (eg. sampling pairs). Depending on how large N is, this value should converge with NlogN samples.

Comment: Are you referencing the Central Limit Theorem? Perhaps you can expand your answer?

Comment: I am actually not very sure. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination

Answer (score 0):

Since every string is a vector in some metric space (where every char is particular coordinate), my solution is to find the distance between the set `A` and some point *P*.

Let's look at one metric's property - the triangle inequality:

```
Distance(x, y) <= Distance(x, *P*) + Distance(y, *P*)
```

So we can find an upper bound of `Sum(Distance(All pairs in A))` as `|A| * Sum(Distance(All elements in A to point P)`:

```
  Sum(Distance(x, y))      N * Sum(x, *P*)     Sum(x, *P*)
---------------------- <= ----------------- = ------------
     N*(N+1)/2               N*(N+1)/2          (N+1)/2
```

This point *P* can be random point or the center of mass (in this case you find an average radius of set) of set `A` or empty string (zero point) or anything else. Generally speaking *P* may be any hyperplane. Anyway you'll find some kind of average radius (or diameter) of your set.
Maybe some linear pre-transformation [of set or coordinate system, which is the same] is good. Or iterate multiple times and on every iteration find the distance to new random hyperplane.

Hope this may help!